# Order of elements in finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that 5448 has order 5^4 in Z/11251Z. How do I show this quickly, I know that all elements must have an order that divides order(Z/11251) according to lagrange's theorem but how do i pinpoint that it is 5^4 and not 5^3 or 5^2?

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate that
$$
5448^{5^4} \equiv 1 \pmod{11251} \quad\text{and}\quad 5448^{5^3} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{11251},
$$
then that is enough to prove that the order of $5448$ modulo $11251$ equals $5^4$. Do you see why?

Those calculations can be done quickly with fast modular exponentiation - hopefully that's something you've been shown.

Comment: I was doing this but 5448^(5^4) is not that easy to calculate?

Comment: Not as an integer, no, but modulo 11251, the calculation is indeed easy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation